If an article has been released under an open access license, is its corresponding questionnaire also open-access?
I am interested in using a questionnaire found within the appendix of an article that has been released under a CC BY 4.0 International License. Am I free to use this questionnaire (in accordance with the article's CC BY license) for my own work, or would I need to contact the authors for permission to use it?

I would presume that the point of publishing it under CC-BY was to allow people to use the questionnaire (after all that's the point in developing it and publishing it). It's good to ask, but it would never have crossed my mind that the questionnaire wasn't usable.

Unless the appendix has a separate license, which would need to be stated explicitly, anything published under such a license can be used elsewhere. Don't forget to give credit, however. If you republish the questionnaire it should include the author's name.
Note that I'm assuming that the article and its appendix have been published as one. If the original was separate from its appendix then a separate license would be required, which might require contacting the authors or other copyright holders.
Note however, that "use" is a loaded word. You can "use" copyrighted, unlicensed work. But you can't republish it (copy it). The ideas within copyrighted work (like all ideas) are free. Ethics requires giving proper attribution, but the CC-BY license goes beyond that. The license applies to the words and expression used.
It might be useful to contact the original authors, however, especially if you are trying to replicate their work. They may have useful suggestions.
